# CreateSymbolicLinkProc fails for ordinary users

Tags: c++, admin, kernel32

I have an issue with CreateSymbolicLinkProc, which I am trying to execute from a C++ application. It works fine, but only if you execute it as a user with Administrator privileges. This is a problem for me, because I need this to work as a non-admin user. I do not want to do this with the clunky mklink system command, because the unsightly DOS command box pops up when you execute the system command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege to create symbolic links, which is set only for members of the Administrators group by default. You can change the settings in the Local Security Policy console. Note that `mklink` will not work without the privilege either.